# connect to replicated Postgresql through Pg_bouncer deployed on local cluster using Minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, pgbouncer

I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm, I took time to read the docs to understand the concepts to move on with my task which I mentioned in the question's title.

I looked for the examples and based on what I see in the [docs & values example](https://github.com/timescale/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/timescaledb-single), I can add pg_bouncer to create the connection pool.

So, the commands that I run with the values.yaml file is :

- minikube start
- `helm install comp-db timescale/timescaledb-single --version 0.13.1 -f ./values.yml`
- wait for the pods (3 replicas) to be ready
- minikube tunnel ( to expose the LoadBalancer, so that I can connect to it )

The problem is that the Helm Release gets created successfully, I can see the Statefulset,Pods,Svcs and I can connect and exec statements through pgAdmin GUI, but I keep getting the following error on node app, where i intend to connect and run the migrations.

```
error:migrate eaa24d98 migrations error: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "172.17.0.1", user "superuser", database "postgres", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/jafar/Desktop/dev/wave/wave_stores/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/jafar/Desktop/dev/wave/wave_stores/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/jafar/Desktop/dev/wave/wave_stores/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/jafar/Desktop/dev/wave/wave_stores/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 169,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '477',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
} +0ms
```

I don't know why this ip address gets applied, although I provide the ip address that I get from the tunnel.

the values that I'm providing is as follows:

```
image:
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: pg13.6-ts2.6.1-latest
timescaledbTune:
        enabled: true
loadBalancer:
        enabled: false
replicaLoadbalancer:
        enabled: false
secrets:
  credentialsSecretName: "comp-db-credentials"
patroni:
  bootstrap:
    dcs:
      postgresql:
        parameters:
          ssl: 'off'  # disable all ssl connections to not require Patroni certificate
          shared_buffers: '8028MB'                                                 
          effective_cache_size: '24084MB'
          maintenance_work_mem: '2047MB'
          work_mem: '10275kB'
          timescaledb:
                  max_background_workers: 8
          max_worker_processes: 19
          max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 4
          max_parallel_workers: 8
          wal_buffers: '16MB'
          min_wal_size: '512MB'
          max_wal_size: '1GB'
          max_connections: 150
          autovacuum_max_workers: 10
          autovacuum_naptime: '5s'
          default_statistics_target: 500
          random_page_cost: 1.1
          checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
          max_connections: 150
          max_locks_per_transaction: 1000
          autovacuum_max_workers: 10
          autovacuum_naptime: 10
          effective_io_concurrency: 256
  postgresql:
    pg_hba:
    - local     all             postgres                            peer           
    # pgBouncer connections will come through local
    - local     all             all               all               md5
    - hostnossl all,replication all               all               md5 
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
pgBouncer:
  enabled: true
  config: 
    max_client_conn: 1000
    default_pool_size: 36
    client_tls_sslmode: allow
    server_tls_sslmode: allow
  pg_hba:
  - local     all postgres                   peer
  - host      all postgres,standby 0.0.0.0/0 reject
  - host      all postgres,standby ::0/0     reject
  - hostssl   all all              0.0.0.0/0 md5
  - hostssl   all all              ::0/0     md5
  - hostnossl all all              0.0.0.0/0 md5
  - hostnossl all all              ::0/0     md5
```

I also tried to update the `pg_hba` for Postgresql to the following to allow connections but the error still exists.

```
         pg_hba:
         - local     all             postgres                              peer
         - local     all             all                                   md5
         - hostnossl all,replication all                all                md5
         - hostssl   all             all                127.0.0.1/32       md5
         - hostssl   all             all                ::1/128            md5
         - hostssl   replication     standby            all                md5
         - hostssl   all             all                all                md5
```

I have searched for this error and similar questions and answers here, but didn't find any that can help me to resolve the issue. Thoughts?